# Animating a borderColor with jQueryUI

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a series of div's that I want to highlight with a blue border, animating in on mouseenter, and out on mouseleave.  When a div is clicked, it should retain it's border until a new div is clicked, which then animates the previous selection back to a white border.

Using the following code, the borders fade in, but they don't fade out:

```
$('div').hover(function(){
  if (!$(this).hasClass('sel')) {
    $(this).stop().animate({borderColor:'#0000ff'}, 2000);      
  }
},function(){
  if (!$(this).hasClass('sel')) {
    $(this).stop().animate({borderColor:'#ffffff'}, 2000);
  }
}).click(function(e){
  $('.sel').not(this).stop().animate({borderColor:'#ffffff'}, 2000).removeClass('sel');
  $(this).addClass('sel');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/reEsa/

Comment: I switched the color to Green (http://jsfiddle.net/N4u8T/) and noticed that jQueryUI changes a color to white before animating.  Any ideas for a workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the border goes to white first, and then changes to the specified color, rather than going to the color directly.  Maybe submit a bug report to jQuery if it has not been already.

I did a workaround where I placed the divs inside a parent div, and made the padding 4 to simulate the border.  I gave the parent div a white background, then animated the background color of the parent div.  I removed the clicking just to show the problem case.

[jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/reEsa/4/)

I would wrap this in a short little jQuery plugin, that appends the div you call it on to a new div that the plugin  creates to make it easier to code and read when you are actually applying it.

Let me know if you have any questions and I will be happy to try to answer them.

Comment: Good call.  I wasn't sure if animating a backgroundColor would suffer from the same issue as a borderColor.  I wrapped all of my div's in div's, and it looks fine now.  Bug report filed at http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/7957

Comment: Glad it is working for you.  Just to keep the post current, your bug report was closed as a duplicate of another bug.  The working ticket is [#6969](http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/6969)